# Multiple Project Gradle Config

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have 2 projects structured in

```
--app (Project 1)
    --build.gradle (Application Project Level - Need 5.x ) 
--services (Project 2)<br>
    --build.gradle (Services Project Level - Cann't support more than 2.x) <br>
--build.gradle (Top Level) 
--gradlew 
--settings.gradle
```

Can I configure my "services project" to use a specific gradle version only ? 
Currently I have constraint that restrict me for updating my gradle version.

Previously it was configured to use 2.x (gradle wrapper) and it was working fine and building both app and service project. 
I have to update the version to 4.x but there is a constraint that will not accept for services project to build higher that 2.x. Can it both separated and build? 



Can we have 2 projects configured to use 2 different versions for gradle and 1 gradle wrapper?

Comment: Missed few more info:
Previously it was configured to use 2.x (gradle wrapper) and it was working fine and building both app and service project.  
<br>I have to update the version to 4.x but there is a constraint that will not accept for services project to build higher that 2.x. 
Can it both separated and build?

Answer (score 2):

The way to go in this case would be the [Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) which is local to your project only. As you'll see in the link from the Gradle docs:

> The Wrapper is a script that invokes a declared version of Gradle,
>   downloading it beforehand if necessary.

Which is exactly what you want.

- To have it readily configured for your coworkers, check in the wrapper to your version control system, namely the two files `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `gradle-wrapper.jar` in the directory `YourProject\gradle\wrapper\`.
- If until now you executed Gradle using the command line: `gradle (arguments)`, now to use the wrapper you'll execute `./gradlew (arguments)` with the same arguments *inside your project folder*.
- If you use an IDE, when you import the project there will be an option to use the gradle wrapper. Choose that.

The Gradle docs in the mentioned links have a good documentation on how to set up the Gradle wrapper, use it and upgrade it to a later version.

It goes without saying but you don't need to change anything in your buildscript (`build.gradle` file). The wrapper is not a different application, it just makes sure that the correct Gradle version is invoked.

Comment: Hi tryman,
I have to configure it for other people to check in and use without downloading. Previously it was configured to use 2.x and it was working fine and building both app and service project. I have to update the version to 4.x but there is a constraint that will not accept for services project to build higher that 2.x. Can you please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: If the gradle wrapper is checked in to your version control, the other people will only have to import the project (to the IDE). The wrapper will download and use the correct version of Gradle (in your case the 2.x you have configured it for) and the rest of your team will never even need to learn what Gradle is. If they use the command line, they'll just have to replace `gradle (args)` with `./gradlew (args)`.

Comment: Thanks tryman, Can we have 2 projects configured to use 2 different versions for gradle and 1 gradle wrapper in that case?

Comment: I guess you mean your two projects in the OP and not some unrelated projects in the same machine. Unfortunately none that I am aware of (apart from building the projects separately). It is my understanding that Gradle needs to see the whole picture of your build to optimize/analyze and process it. Maybe use the `wrapper` task inside the subprojects' different buildscript and specify a different wrapper version? I doubt that would work, it would probably fail or have undocumented behavior. In your case, I'd focus on trying to find a single compatible Gradle version for both projects.

Comment: Let's leave this question open and see if other contributors have anything to say. I initially misunderstood your problem as to how to enforce a specific Gradle version which is a common problem in the Gradle community. Also, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57452710/edit) your question to add your clarification (in the question's comments), it's meant to be read alltogether.

Comment: Thanks for your help tryman, Hope some one will help to resolve it and thanks for your suggestions.